# Moq WebApi async method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, moq

I'm new to testing with Moq, so I'm confused a bit regarding `ReturnsAsync`.
Here is my test method, where I'm expecting `ReturnsAsync` should receive type that will be returned by method defined in `Setup`. Am I right?

But seemed `ReturnsAsync` should have the other signature - it's looking for `Func` delegate.

```
[TestClass]
public class TourObjectControllerTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task GetTourObjects()
    {
        var mockService = new Mock<ITourObjectService>(MockBehavior.Default);
        mockService.Setup(x => x.GetAll()).ReturnsAsync(new Task<IEnumerable<TourObjectDTO>>);
        var controller = new TourObjectController(mockService.Object);
        var result = await controller.Get();
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        Assert.AreSame(typeof(TourObjectViewModel), result);
    }
}
```

Method under test:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TourObjectViewModel>> Get()
{
    IEnumerable<TourObjectViewModel> viewmodel = null;
    try
    {
        var tourobjects = await _tos.GetAll();
        viewmodel = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<TourObjectViewModel>>(tourobjects);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.ErrorFormat("Method:{0} <br/> Error: {1}", System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ex);
    }
    return viewmodel;
}
```

Comment: What does Intellisense say? (I assume you're working in VS.)

Comment: @KennethK., it say that Task<IEnumerable<..>> is not assignable to type Func<IEnurable<...>>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass an actual result.

Assuming `ITourObjectService.GetAll()` returns `Task<IEnumerable<TourObjectDTO>>`

eg

```
[TestClass]
public class TourObjectControllerTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task GetTourObjects()
    {
        var fakeData = new List<TourObjectDTO>() {
            new TourObjectDTO { ... }
        };
        var mockService = new Mock<ITourObjectService>(MockBehavior.Default);
        mockService.Setup(x => x.GetAll()).ReturnsAsync(fakeData);
        var controller = new TourObjectController(mockService.Object);
        var result = await controller.Get();
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        Assert.IsTry(typeof(IEnumerable<TourObjectViewModel>).IsAssignableFrom(result.GetType());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, Moq generate random data of type IEnumerable<TourObjectViewModel>?

Comment: No it does not. not without some extension or plugin

Comment: Well, so how this simulate repository/service behaviour?

Comment: You are mocking the service and providing some fake data to return when the mocked member is called.

Comment: Test failed even with actual result - Error in Assert.IsNotNull()

Comment: Check mapping. that is the point where it assigns return value. debug and step through to see what happens at that line.

Comment: Has mapper been configured for the test?

Answer (score 1):

`ReturnsAsync()` should take a return value as the paramter instead of `Task<TReurnValue>`. For example, next 2 lines of code are equal (by behavior):

```
mockService.Setup(x => x.GetAll()).ReturnsAsync(new List<TourObjectDTO>());
mockService.Setup(x => x.GetAll()).Returns(Task.FromResult(new List<TourObjectDTO>()));
```

You need to replace `new List<TourObjectDTO>()` with your test data which you want to retrieve in the test from the mock. For example, you can create just few test values:

```
var testData = new [] { new TourObjectDTO(1, "test1"), new TourObjectDTO(2, "test2") };
mockService.Setup(x => x.GetAll()).ReturnsAsync(testData);
```

or create fake data generator if needed.

Note that `ReturnsAsync()` is only available for methods that return a `Task<T>`. For methods that return only a `Task`, `.Returns(Task.FromResult(default(object)))` can be used.

Comment: Yes, method GetAll return Task<IEnumerable<OfSomeClass>>

Comment: @andrey.shedko ok then just pass an expected value for this method as an parameter of ReturnsAsync or use Returns with Task.Result as in the code above.